# How to test tooltip for any mouse activity with selenium webdriver in java?

Tags: java, tooltip, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test a tool tip option for mouseover activity on a web image element. How to make sure whether the tool tip is being displayed or not ? here the problem is, in Mozilla, multi-line tool tip will be displayed as single line only. Can anyone help me out on how to test these things ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
WebElement Element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='badge_people']/li[1]/img"));
Thread.sleep(6000);
builder.moveToElement(Element1).perform();
System.out.println("User Name :"+ driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='badge_people']/div/div[2]")).getText());
builder.moveToElement(Element1).release().perform();
```